# IE8 jQuery input in function call error

Tags: jquery, function, input, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting the following error in IE8 while calling a function.
[image]

Line 13 is the line with "$input" in the following code:

```
    $.getScript('/assets/js/inc/ajax-request.js', function() {
        new AjaxRequest(
            "/cms/ajax/validatelogin.php",
            $inputs,
            serializedData
        );
    });
```

$inputs is equal to:

```
$(this).find("input[type='text'], input[type='password']");
```

Where $(this) = current form.

I though IE8 couldn't handle the input[type='password'] but even when I delete that piece of code it still doesn't work.

In all modern browsers everything works fine.
I have no idea what is going wrong or where I need to look for some information/help about this.

So I hope some of you folks can help me out, thanks instead.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? And what is `AjaxRequest`? Where did you define that?

Comment: I'm using jQuery version 1.9. AjaxRequest is a long function I call that handles a Ajax request of a POST form to the server. I define that in the file that I load via $.getScript, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I see this error when creating an object. IE hates trailing commas.

```
var myObj = {
    'first': 1,
    'second' : 2,
}
```

vs

```
var myObj = {
    'first': 1,
    'second' : 2
}
```

Is there other code around this that may have this problem?
Is there maybe a line that ends with a comma instead of a semi-colon?

Comment: I double checked everything, but no where seems to be a comma on the last parameter.